# Problem with return specific type base on argument in subclass

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with one method. I do not understand why. If Typescript knows that the action variable is of type A[K], why doesn't the return type match?

```js
getActionParams<K extends keyof A>(actionName: K): ReturnType<A[K]['getAvailableParams']> {
    const action: A[K] = this.actions[actionName];

    return action.getAvailableParams();
}
```

I have error

```
Type '{ [x: string]: ProjectParameters; }' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<A[K]["getAvailableParams"]>'.
```

I prepared full example in TS playground:

[EXAMPLE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwYEM5YLYDOAalgDYoQFQC8UA3gFBTNQDaA5hAHYRwCWaAMLIIALigFg-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-UoL5jMwHcmpOsSc8euTHeJfK8tcAcXwCAA6YcU5xtkfJ+LRhUOUvjdUpv7zRbZ-PgzsHIdJ-z4Dw-d5Qby6-VlcAQCa+X6yVieRU3O5q+EETyyHW5q9pIy4UmOb40Lk05zgujqsHBXAXvYrTtOaOrAHqlKIbOX7Kj+jx-m8a7ojGjrAH0eIEkSJJbpStA8AA7lAuL4pwNGkkmxHtAA9DxUAAOpcj8JQsVyEqCGUZF9lAYB-lBaBUexCDEpxK64Zu36qoRdgENxGLkVA7CICgYBQUx8bWImK56XQlFsYSKm0UmNavPofFQGUACaMDBLJf4AExQCUAASbKCgUkpQHyfnBAAioKvgFJ5bKeT5fkAAYgRRcm6Rl0mgblWxBbQxkIKZGnWRSO7PJ4ikORxdGeG57RAA)

Comment: You should update the question to include all the relevant code.

Comment: @possum I added link to TS playground with full code. I can`t add full code directly because of validation :(

Comment: A link to the code *is not the code*.  This purpose of this site is to have your question possibly be useful to others in the future.  Linked code can go away or change and it defeats the entire purpose of this site.

Comment: @possum I agree but i have a error when I try add full code: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." 

Is there any way I can get around this? I have no idea what else I could write about problem :/

Comment: Yes, you should trim it down to a *minimal reproducible example*.  You should review the rules and guidelines first.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think one of your biggest problems is the complexity from mixing abstract classes, class inheritance, and generics. Idiomatic TypeScript mostly revolves around functions and plain old objects.

Comment: @possum Yes it is minimal reproducible example. The original has over 1000 lines of code in many files. Thanks to people like you, it's easier to write @ts-ignore than to struggle with people while looking for help. My English isn't good enough to write a lot description and stackoverflow validation doesn't allow me to add these 60 lines of code :/ If someone explains to me where the problem is, I will probably be able to write smaller reproducible example but right now i can`t

Comment: You've truly misunderstood the purpose of this site.  stackoverflow is successful because it has pretty reasonable rules about how to ask questions, what is expected in a question, what constitutes a good answer, and how moderation is done.   This is not a general help forum.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is logically correct and fine. It's just too complex for TypeScript compiler to handle. Sometimes, in such edge cases, TypeScript can't simply infer the result type.

In this case, just cast it using the as keyword.

```js
getActionParams<K extends keyof A>(actionName: K) {
    const action: A[K] = this.actions[actionName];

    return action.getAvailableParams() as ReturnType<A[K]['getAvailableParams']>;
}
```

Comment: The question was *why* the issue occurs.  This just works around it and writes it off to "it's just too complex"

Comment: @possum As I mentioned, TSC SIMPLY CANNOT infer the type in this case (name it a bug). That's why. Also, he can open an issue on the TypeScript GitHub page, though.